# Android menu item set to always be shown is not being shown

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, menu, android-actionbar

Using `app:showAsAction="always"` for a menu item in Android is not showing the menu item in the `Action Bar`. Instead, the item is shown in a drop-down together with menu items having `app:showAsAction="never"`. Here are the codes:

**menu_main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="myAppID.MainActivity" >
<item android:id="@+id/action_one"
    android:title="One"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
<item android:id="@+id/action_two"
    android:title="Two"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item android:id="@+id/action_three"
    android:title="Three"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Additional info: I am not using `AppCompat`. I noticed that when `AppCompat` is used, the behaviour of the menu item is correct.

How can I fix this without `AppCompat`?

Comment: You need an icon as well.

Comment: Add an icon or set `app:showAsAction="always|withText"`

Comment: @MohammadOmidvar Not working,

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal Not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of app:showAsAction change it to android:showAsAction as shown:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context="myAppID.MainActivity" >
      <item android:id="@+id/action_one"
          android:title="One"
          android:icon="@drawable/your_icon"
          android:showAsAction="always" />
      <item android:id="@+id/action_two"
          android:title="Two"
          android:showAsAction="never" />
      <item android:id="@+id/action_three"
          android:title="Three"
          android:showAsAction="never" />
  </menu>
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding the icon does not help.

Comment: I have updated the question. Adding the icon is still not showing the menu item in the Action Bar.

Comment: @Kamil instead of app:showAsAction use android:showAsAction and try

Comment: Yes this works! I also needed to add `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'` in the app-level build.gradle. Please update your answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method

```
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: How is this answer related to the question ?